# How to exclude oauth2 redirect URI from ViewControllerRegistry as it does not have /api on that path

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, react-router-dom

I have spring boot (backend) application combined with React(Frontend), So both are packaged as one war file and deployed into tomcat apache, In order to make react routing work from Spring boot I had to add configuration in spring boot and it works. Below is the configuration I added.All the paths that includes api strings are expected to serve by spring boot and that is working as well.

```
@Configuration
public class WebRouteConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
     
    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        // Map "/"
        registry.addViewController("/")
                .setViewName("forward:/index.html");

        // Single directory level - no need to exclude "api"
        registry.addViewController("/{x:[\\w\\-]+}")
                .setViewName("forward:/index.html");
        
        registry.addViewController("/{x:^(?!api$).*$}/{y:[\\w\\-]+}")
        .setViewName("forward:/index.html");
        // Multi-level directory path, need to exclude "api" on the first part of the path
        registry.addViewController("/{x:^(?!api$).*$}/ABC/{y:[\\w\\-]+}")
                .setViewName("forward:/index.html");
       
        
    }
```

But I wanted to exclude oauth redirect URI(path=oauth/redirect) here , As it does not have "api" string in that so it's being redirected to frontend where it does not have routing configured for that path. Spring boot is expected to receive oauth/redirect page without routing to react routing, could some body please help me how to exclude from the registry for this particular path.